# How to prevent login prompt for guest users via Integrated Windows Authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos, windows-authentication

I have Tomcat application and I want to add support for Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). I want to the following behavior:

1. If user is domain authenticated user - I want to get user name from request (IWA itself)
2. If user is not domain authenticated user - I just want to show my custom page with form to login and authenticate it manually.

So, my application has the following workflow:

1. user loads static AngularJS page
2. This page makes AJAX request to the URL like /login/check_iwa
3. Server side for /login/check_iwa sends 401 WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
4. if the user is a domain user - then the browser will resend the request with the user's credentials, if not - nothing happens, JS gets 401 and understands that the user is a guest.

And I have problem at step 4. IE and Chrome always show login prompt (with FF there is no login prompt) for guest users. 
Is there a way to avoid login prompt? I have my own beautiful form for login, I don't want native login prompt for guest user. 
It seems, that I need only Kerberos authentication, but IE and Chrome use NTLM authentication with login prompt.

Do I need to send 401 WWW-Authenticate: Kerberos instead of Negotiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup dialog in IE is hardcoded, you won't get it away. It is querying for alternative credentials which are passed to SSPI. Switching to Kerberos instead of Negotaite will give you nothing because no browser (IE, Chrome, FF) support Kerberos directly but through SPNEGO only. You are out of luck. You are probably better off with `Basic` if SPNEGO fails but at the end, failing Kerberos in an enterprise environment simply means that your network setup is faulty and needs to be fixed.

Edit: Since you want to serve intranet and Internet users, you need a sifting authenticator. If you happen to use an `Authenticator` on Tomcat side, you could easily write a `SiftingAuthenticator` which decides based on the range of IP addresses what succinct authenticator is best. Use the `CombinedRealm` as template.

Comment: That's the point - my application should work for both internet and intranet. Without login prompts for both cases.
As I understood, it's imporssible :(

Comment: There is a chance to solve this. If you know what IP range your intranet users have, you could serve the according login method. This would give a clear distinction between both.